# Copy profile button on Somebody Else's Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I see a "**Copy Area51 Profile To Related Accounts**" button on [Somebody Else's Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem).

[image]

Here's the [problem](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/33907?tab=accounts#tab-top). ;)

Comment: That's great! I wonder whether it works...

Comment: If you want to become a *StackStalker*, yeah, I guess it's "great"...

Comment: @muntoo, do you imagine it would copy _their_ profile to yours? or copy _their_ profile to _theirs_? (as if they had pressed the button)

Comment: @davidsleeps Are you going to try it? :) One minute later: *StackExchange crashes. All data lost. Skynet imported.*

Comment: These reports should be posted on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/; there is a tag to use for Area 51 issues (_area51-meta_).

Comment: Those buttons don't do anything, though; they keep to return an error. They should not be visible if users are not visiting their own profile page, that is true.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Actually, A51 questions are permitted on MSO, as per our FAQ. In fact, there was a [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76781/does-area-51-now-have-its-own-meta) about whether it belonged on discuss (which was supposed to be about specific proposals only), and the consensus was that MSO was where such questions belonged.

Comment: @waiwai933 I was referring to this [Robert Cartaino's answer](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/are-questions-about-area-51-still-on-topic-on-mso/1620#1620).

Comment: Also, you can tell it is Somebody Else's Profile because it says `java developer`. 1) I use proper English. 2) I write paragraphs; not just two words. 3) It's **[JAVA](http://www.jwz.org/doc/java.html)!!!** 'Nuff said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops! The button has been removed. Thanks for that. (For the record, clicking the button on someone else's profile led to a 404.)